# How to verify table's column data is sorted by name or not

Tags: cypress, pageobjects

I have one project where I want to do some sorting. When the user click on the column name data should be show in sorted by name.

Is it possible to do in Cypress using POM?

Comment: Add the code you tried along with the HTML of your app.

Comment: @AlapanDas Thank you for responding. Actually have not tried anything because I don't know how to do that. I am expecting from you. because I have learned many from your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the column data from the page, then sort it. Afterwards, click on app sort by name and match.

Here is a working simplified [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/integration/checkSortedColumn.md).

```js
cy.get('.selector-to-get-column-data')
  .then(($el) => {
    // use lodash .map() to get innerText of each element
    // then sort the array
    return Cypress._.map($el, "innerText").sort();
  })
  .as("sortedArray")

// action to sort column

cy.get("@sortedArray").then((sortedArray) => {
  cy.get(".selector-to-get-column-data")
    .then(($el) => {
      // use lodash .map() to get innerText of each element
      // then sort the array
      return Cypress._.map($el, "innerText").sort();
    })
    .then(cy.log)
    .should("deep.equal", sortedArray);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with all the elements in sorted order in lower case. Then after sorting extract each text from the column and match it against the array elements.

```js
cy.get('selector').click() //To trigger the sorting

//Save the sorted texts in a array
const sortedTexts = ['apple', 'ball', 'cat', 'dice']

//Loop over column texts and match it agains the sortedTexts
cy.get('column-selector').each(($ele, index) => {
  expect($ele.text().toLowercase().trim()).to.equal(sortedTexts[index])
})
```

In case you have a dynamic list, you can create two arrays one before sorting and one after sorting, then compare the two, something like this:

```js
var beforeSort = []
var afterSort = []
cy.get('column-selector').each(($ele) => {
  beforeSort.push($ele.text().trim())
})

cy.get('selector').click() //To trigger the sorting

cy.get('column-selector').each(($ele) => {
  afterSort.push($ele.text().trim())
}).then(() => {
  expect(beforeSort.sort()).to.eq(afterSort)
})
```

Comment: In the table, there is real-time data. so can we make it a dynamic array? i.e. First extract data from the table and then match? I don't know how but something that because every time data should be different.